# How to force onClick to take parent view width as clickable area?

Tags: android, view, onclicklistener

I have an `activity` contains a **parent view** along with some **dynamically created children views**, according to my app needs, these views **width** are set **dynamically** through the run-time so that I can't set it to `match_parent`, the problem here is that I want to assign an `onClickListener` to these views but want to make it functionable through the whole *parent view* width, to be more specific look at the following picture:

[image]

in the past picture the each `View` width is represented in **red**, and all I want is to assign *each View* `onClick` function to the whole width represented in **green**.
is that possible?

Comment: you can set dynamically created views width to match_parent. You need to use LayoutParams of corresponding root layout

Answer (score 0):

You can set `LayoutParams` to your `View`

```
LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        yourparentview.setContentView(yourchildview, layoutParams);
```